# Unicode with active_directory

Tags: python, active-directory

I'm using the [active_directory](http://tgolden.sc.sabren.com/python/active_directory.html) module, and trying to print a list of the users. My code is:

```
import active_directory as ad
users = ad.AD_Object("LDAP://OU=Home, DC=dome, DC=net")
for user in users.search(objectCategory="Person"):
    print str(user)
```

It prints some of the users until it meets an unicode username. Then it throws the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: `ascii` codec
>   can't encode characthers in position
>   10-14: ordinaal not in range(128).

What can I do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print user.decode('utf-8')
```